# Can truncate Magento catalog_product_entity_int table?

Tags: magento

In magento db table `catalog_product_entity_int` too much large near about 500 MB and due to this performence is low.

How we can reduce the size or can this table truncate as like we can log tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can not truncate `catalog_product_entity_int` table.**

In Magento database, an entity can have several tables that share the same prefix.

For example, the product entity has the *`catalog_product_entity`* table for its main data and several other tables prefixed with “`catalog_product_`” such as `catalog_product_entity_int`, `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`, `catalog_product_entity_text` and so on.

```
To store the data more efficiently, product details are stored separately depending on their data types.
```

When the value of the data is an integer type, it’s saved in the `catalog_product_entity_int` table, and when its type is an image, it’s saved in the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table.

---

if you want truncate table for performance
 then you can truncate below table i think you got lots of data in this table

- log_customer
- log_visitor
- log_visitor_info
- log_url_info
- log_quote
- report_viewed_product_index
- report_compared_product_index
  -catalog_compare_item

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: you can not truncate catalog_product_entity_int table.